# C#: pg_restore to different schema

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have .net application which is trying to get data dump using *pg_dump* and restore using *pg_restore*.

Here is my data dump code:

```
public string GetStringArgument()
{
  return string.Format("-i -h {0} -p {1} -U {2} -F c -b -v -f {3} -n {4} {5}", _dbCredential.Server, _dbCredential.Port.ToString(), _dbCredential.User, GetFilename(), "public", _dbCredential.Database);
}
```

I'm getting all datatables on **public** schema.

Now I need to restore this data dump on my postgres server using pg_restore.

```
public string GetStringArgument()
{
  return string.Format("-i -h {0} -p {1} -U {2} -d {3} {4}", _dbCredential.Server, _dbCredential.Port.ToString(), _dbCredential.User, _dbCredential.Database, _dbCredential.BackUpPath);
}
```

But I need to restore this data bump to different data schema called **stack**.

This is windows service application and I cann't do any manual script changes.

how can I restore my data dump into different schema ?

Appreciate your feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore to different schema using pg_restore

All I can do is restore to default schema(whatever the schema which you got from data base) and rename it.